# How do I call a C++ static library from Perl?

Tags: c++, perl

I'm writing a C++ static library that needs to be shared among several applications, one of them written in Perl.  Unfortunately, I only barely know the core Perl language (I read the Llama book), and I'm not all that familiar with its libraries.  How do you make calls to an external C++ binary from a Perl script?

By Google search, I found information on the Perl [Inline](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/Inline-0.44/Inline.pod) module, but if I understand it correctly, that isn't what I need.  I'm pretty sure that's for writing C and C++ code directly in your Perl scripts, not for calling external C++ libraries.

The C++ static library is being cross-compiled for an ARM processor, so there will be no C++ compiler on the target machine where the Perl script will be running. (If that makes a difference.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look at using XS, which is how Perl normally interfaces with C/C++ libraries.  It's not quite trivial.  A couple of relevant portions of the Perl documentation:

- [perlxs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html)
- [perlxstut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can call code from other libraries via Inline::C (and likely the same via Inline::CPP) - have a look at [Inline::C::Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.45/C/C-Cookbook.pod). Most likely you want to start out with Inline and after you're done experimenting use the resulting .XS file to work further.

Answer (score 4):

First, it does need to be in a dynamic library, not a static library (unless you'll be re-compiling perl itself and linking it against your static library).

Second, since C++ will mangle the names (one of the most annoying "Features" of C++ if you ask me) you'll need an extern "C" block that contains hook functions. If you were using C++ you could probably get by with a single hook function that returns the C++ object that implements the interface you need to use. Since you're using perl, you may need to wrap an object in an interface like this:

```
CPPObject object;

extern "C"
{

int InitObject( void )
{
  return object.init();
}

int DoCoolStuff( void )
{
  return object.DoCoolStuff();
}

int DoOtherCoolStuff( int foo )
{
  return object.DoOtherCoolStuff( foo );
}

int DestroyObject( void )
{
  return object.Destroy();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a wrapper function that is callable from perl, and AFAIK, you'll need to have this wrapper function be in a dynamic library (unless you're going to rebuild the perl binary and link the static lib to it).  I like to use a tool called [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) (Simple Wrapper Interface Generator) to create the wrappers for me.  It can create wrappers for 17 or so other languages too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you're thinking, but how about writing a stand-alone C++ program that the perl program communicates through pipes with?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only starting to wrap my head around XS, so I can't offer much help.  But here's what I do know...

There is [XSpp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Wx/build/Wx/XSP/XSpp.pod), which is XS for C++.  It is distributed with [WxPerl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Wx/).  WxPerl is under active and responsive development.

Inline:CPP can be used to write your initial interface/wrapper code.  Then you can analyze the generated XS.  However, it doesn't look so well maintianed.  If it works, it may provide you with a good head start.

You might find [this short note on XS and C++ by John Keiser](http://www.johnkeiser.com/perl-xs-c++.html) helpful, if a bit dated.